# printing elements from superclass in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-3.x

Hi i have the following super class

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,building,floor,number):
        self.building=building
        self.floor=floor
        self.number=number
    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.building)+'.'+str(self.floor)+'.'+str(self.number))
```

and the following subclass

```
class Occupant(Room):
    def __init__(self,familyname,givenname,building,floor,number):
        self.familyname=familyname
        self.givenname=givenname
        Room.__init__(self,building,floor,number)
    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.familyname)+', '+str(self.givenname)+......)
```

How can a subclass print elements from the superclass. What i should add to (.....) to take the correct output when i print an object from class Occupant. Thanks

Comment: `occupant` makes no sense whatsoever as a subclass of `room`. Please do not abuse inheritance like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `Occupant` appears to be a person, while a `Room` is a location. 
If so, it does not make sense to say an `Occupant` is a type of `Room`. So `Occupant` should not be a subclass of `Room`. Instead, an `Occupant` *has a* `Room`:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, building, floor, number):
        self.building = building
        self.floor = floor
        self.number = number
    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.building)+'.'+str(self.floor)+'.'+str(self.number))

class Occupant:
    def __init__(self, familyname, givenname, room):
        self.familyname = familyname
        self.givenname = givenname
        self.room = room

    def __str__(self):
        return '{f}, {g} -- {r}'.format(f = self.familyname, g = self.givenname, r = self.room)

room = Room('Building', 'Floor', 'Num')
occ = Occupant('Family', 'Given', room)
print(occ)
# Family, Given -- Building.Floor.Num
```

Comment: Absolute correct! Thanks a lot in 1 min i click as the correct